# How to open one popup at a time and close popup on outside click in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a popup, that must open one at a time. It must open the recent one which is clicked and hide the previously clicked one.
It also doesn't close on outside click.
CAn anyone help me to solve this?

HTML:

```
<td>
          <a (click)="editCondition(rowData)">
            <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" style="color:#0847a1"></i>
          </a>
          <div class="switch-list" id="switch-list" *ngIf="rowData.isViewDetails">
            <a id="ccd_viewdetails" (click)="gotoViewDetails(rowData)">View Details</a>
            <a>Download</a>
          </div>
        </td>
```

TS:

```
 editCondition(rowData) {
    console.log(rowData);
    rowData.isViewDetails = !rowData.isViewDetails;
  }
```

Here is the working demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c16wte?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reset the all `items` of `ccdList`.

Need some small change in your function `editCondition`

```
 editCondition(rowData) {
    this.ccdList.forEach(item=>{
      item.isViewDetails = false;
    })
    console.log(rowData);
    rowData.isViewDetails = !rowData.isViewDetails;
  }
```

For outside click use `HostListener`

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  windowClick($event) {
    let exceptElementFound = false;
    Object.keys($event.target.classList).forEach(key => {
      if ($event.target.classList[key] == "fa-ellipsis-h") {
        exceptElementFound = true;
      }
    })
    if (!exceptElementFound) {
      this.ccdList.forEach(item => {
        item.isViewDetails = false;
      })
    }
  }
```

Working copy is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bbyz8n

Comment: thanks for response but i am not getting how to use hostListener event https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c16wte?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

You can try and make use of `HostListener` in your app.

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
clickOutside(){
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, like how? saw that demo?

Comment: I saw your demo, what you can do is maintain a corresponding `array` of `boolean` which is initially `false`. When you click on one of the popup, you pass `index` of array to your handler, which will `reset` your array to `false` and only make it `true` for that `index`. You can use `ngIf` in your .html to hide and display. For click outside, you can use `HostListener`